# How to set max body length in a minimal .Net Core 6 Web API and allow large uploads when receiving a json object

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

when allowing large uploads in a mvc web application you can specify this in web.config

```
httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx"
```

How do I do the same in appsettings.json for a minimal .Net Core 6 Web API? I'm receiving a large json object in my API and need to set at least 150MB

EDIT:
I added this to try it out.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 209715;
});
```

This works but can I add a http.Response.StatusCode if the posted body is to large compared to what is allowed?

Comment: The documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#maximum-request-body-size

Comment: I tried one approach described in the doc and have updated my original question with a follow up question

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[RequestSizeLimit(40000000)]` attribute if you want to use it per endpoint.

Or, you can also set it during Kestrel setup for entire application, like:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; //50MB
    });
}
```